# Making android application searchable through launcher search bar for few keywords

Tags: android, search, android-manifest, android-launcher

I am working on requirement in Android, where I want my application icon to show in search results from launcher search for particular keywords.

For Example, App name : MyApplication.

As of now, if you type MyApplication or its prefix, MyApplication shows up in result.

I want to index it for few other keywords.

Answer (score 0):

currently: you can't. search is basing on name of app only

future (maybe): you may use [Slices](https://developer.android.com/guide/slices) for showing own app/content in search/assistant suggestions, but it is "in development" since half of 2018. Google announced release before end of 2018, we have 2020...

I bet they realized that when they give developers tools for reacting for almost every query then a lot of apps will start spamming search suggestions, even when their apps won't fit search terms/query

Comment: when i type Taxi, it shows results like "Uber" and "Ola", how it works then ?

Comment: some big companies are treated by own rules sadly... Google is coworking with them and allowing to inject own data to search results - I bet you can order both Uber and Ola through Google Maps (btw. Uber isnt showing for me for "taxi" query)

Comment: i used Samsung Galaxy S8, i think they have customized launcher using bixby or sfinder search. In another device, its not working ("taxi" query)

Comment: so just like you see - big companies are supporting each other, smaller devs don't have chance for this... maybe these Slices linked in answer will change this situation, but I doubt this feature will be released anytime :/ anyway: if you find any way for achieving your purposes let me/us know :) good luck, cheers!

Comment: Commerzbank (it's a German bank) has an app that appears as "Banking" in the Android launcher but can be searched by the "Commerzbank" name in the search bar as well. I doubt that everyone with more than a few thousand downloads contacts google to get their search in the OS custom indexed, sounds wildly exciting as a concept to be followed by thousands of devs. But I haven't found the answer yet unfortunately...

Comment: Commerzbank is already cooperating with Google, they have Google Pay, so they may bargain a bit... huge/powerful players are always privileged and all banking/financial companies belong to this group. please provide a sample, which isn't making any business deals with Google and provide custom search by not-name of app, I bet you won't find anything

Comment: PS. if you find a solution, which allows this, then please post it here. I would immediatelly add "facebook", "google", "news", "weather" etc. hot keywords to all my apps, just for showing my apps icon in another one extra place/suggestion... so extra chance for opening and retaining user, which is a big problem on mobile platforms. Allowing any dev for messing with search suggestions without any check is just huge security and usability flaw, won't happen (read about how Google allowed to advertise on all Androids using Beacons - feature is gone, devs started spamming users near beacons...)

Comment: @snachmsm So, How can I contact Google to put keywords...?

Answer (score -1):

You can create app shortcuts. Launchers on manufactures like Samsung, One Plus (Scout Search) will display your app if user searches for a keyword that matches the label for your shortcut.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts